# Incompatible key type object for Map<id,account>

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, aggregate, after-trigger

I am trying to write apex code (and I'm learning how) to roll up data from the on the Account from an object with a lookup relationship to the object.

Fields from Account:  ID, DealCount__c

Fields from related object - Investment__c:  Target_Company__c (ID from Account), count of records.

when I try saving it, I'm getting the error:  Incompatible key type Object for Map at line 22 column 12. (between **...** in code below)

Code:

```
trigger trgRollUpToAccount on Investment__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    //List to store Account IDs
    List<Id> AccountIDs = new List<Id>(); 
    //Get list of target accounts from investment__c
    for(Investment__c i: Trigger.new) 
    {
        AccountIDs.add(i.Target_Company__c);
    } 
    //query to get all investment records whose account IDs are in the list
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [Select count(id)DealCount, Target_Company__c from Investment__c 
                                        where  Target_Company__c in :AccountIDs Group by Target_Company__c];

    // get group of account objects to update
    Map<id,Account> accountMap = new Map<id,Account>([Select id, DealCount__c from Account where id in :AccountIds]);

    //iterate over grouped results and set the account map's data to match

    **for(AggregateResult ar: groupedResults) 
    { 

        accountMap.get(ar.get('Target_Company__c' )).DealCount__c = ar.get('DealCount');  
    }** 

        //Update account objects:
        try {
            update accountMap.values();
        }
    catch(DmlException e) {
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    } 

}
```

Comment: `ar.get('Target_Company__c')` returns an object, which isn't a valid key. Try casting it to an Id.

Comment: This is a good exercise for learning, but if you want to do this in a production environment I'd recommend using [Andrew Fawcett's Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary Tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) before trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic `get` method returns an `Object`, so you have to cast it to a specific type (`Id` in this case):

**Incorrect**

```
accountMap.get(ar.get('Target_Company__c' ))
```

**Correct**

```
accountMap.get((Id)ar.get('Target_Company__c' ))
```

The longhand would look more like:

```
Id targetCompanyId = (Id)ar.get('Target_Company__c' );
Account targetCompany = accountMap.get(targetCompanyId);
```

Comment: beat me to the edit, and to the answer.